# Suggestions on how I populate my HTML Table in the view from 3 different SQL Tables in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Hope you could help me with my problem here. What I'd like to do is to populate my table in my view from the queried data in 3 different SQL tables.

How do I fill this:
[image: View]

From this data gathered:

[image: data]

MySQL Query:

```
-- Ordered Query

SELECT abstract_supplier.supplier,abstract_supplier.canvasser_name,abstract_supplier.canvasser_department, abstract_items.particulars, abstract_items.qty,abstract_items.unit,abstract_price.unit_price, abstract_price.total_price 
    -> FROM abstract_items
    -> RIGHT JOIN abstract_price ON abstract_price.item_id = abstract_items.id
    -> LEFT JOIN abstract_supplier ON abstract_supplier.id = abstract_price.supplier_id;
```

My Controller:

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $abstract = AbstractModel::find($id);
        $office = Office::all();
        $pr_item = PurchaseRequestItemModel::all()->where('pr_form_number',$abstract->pr_number);
        $grand_total = $pr_item->sum('pr_estimated_cost');

        $abstract_items = abstractitemmodel::all()->where('abstract_id',"=",$abstract->id);

        $query= DB::table('abstract_supplier')
        ->paginate(3);

        // dd($query);
        return view('abstract.abstract-form',compact('abstract','abstract_items','pr_item','grand_total','office','query','supp_query'));
    }
```

My View

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed">
      <thead class="text-center">
        <tr class="center-t">
            <th  rowspan="3" class="col-xs-3">Particulars</th>
            <th rowspan="3" class="col-xs-1">Qty</th>
            <th  rowspan="3" class="col-xs-1">Unit</th>

            @php $counter = 0; @endphp
            @foreach($query as $key => $suppliername)
            @php $counter++; @endphp
            <th colspan="2" class="col-xs-2">Supplier {{$counter}}</th>     
            @endforeach
            @if($query->count() < 3)
                @for($i = $query->count(); $i < 3; $i++)
                <th colspan="2" class="col-xs-2">Supplier</th>
                @endfor
            @endif

        </tr>
        <tr>

            @foreach($query as $indexKey => $suppliers)
            <td colspan="2" class="col-xs-2 someCell">{{$suppliers->supplier}}</td>
            @endforeach
            @if($query->count() < 3)
                @for($i = $query->count(); $i < 3; $i++)
                <td colspan="2" class="col-xs-2">N/A</td>
                @endfor
            @endif



        </tr>
        <tr class="center-t">

            @foreach($query as $key => $prices)
            <th class="col-xs-1">Price/Unit</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Price/Item</th>
            @endforeach
            @if($query->count() < 3)
                @for($i = $query->count(); $i < 3; $i++)
                <th class="col-xs-1">Price/Unit</th>
                <th class="col-xs-1">Price/Item</th>
                @endfor
            @endif

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($abstract_items as $key2 => $items)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$items->particulars}}</td>
            <td>{{$items->qty}}</td>
            <td>{{$items->unit}}</td>
            @foreach($query as $price_key => $prices)
            <td  class="text-right"></td>
            <td  class="text-right"></td>
            @endforeach
            @if($query->count() < 3)
                @for($i = $query->count(); $i < 3; $i++)
                <td class="col-xs-1">N/A</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1">N/A</td>
                @endfor
            @endif
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$query->links()}}
</div>
```

As you can see, I used foreach to loop and fill the table but the results is not what I expected, I'd like your insights and suggestions on how I can approach this.

Comment: Oi this has some work ahead. I am out of time at the momemt. If it is still not answered by tomorrow i will lend my aid. Meanwhile I would advise to look into eloquent relationships and pass the data through an hydrator then a marshaller so your view only worries about display.

Comment: @DiogoSanto for real. I'm new to the terms hydrator, and marshaller. What are those?

Comment: So they are adopted patterns (non mandatory) done by some of the frameworks. I have seen them and found them quite great to use as default rule when applying code. So for example, a Hydrator will take the responsibility of populating objects/arrays with the required content and variables that is needed for certain view. Meanwhile a Marshaller is responsible to parse the data in a way we wish to present to the view. You can read more about marshallers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)).

Comment: It does not mean you would use both, it depends on how you plan the structure of your program I would say. And sometimes data is simple enough to not justify an Hydrator, for example. But I have understood lately that normally we can make use of Marshallers more commonly :)

Comment: I have a question from inspecting your code. What is your `AbstractModel` supposed to be?

Comment: here: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'abstract';

    protected $fillable = [
     'id',
     'created_at',
     'created_by' ,
     'abstract_no',
     'pr_number',
     'proc_details',
     'office',
     'requestor_name'
    ];

    
}
`

Comment: Why did you name it **AbstractModel**? Does it have a concrete class that is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I would rename your **AbstractModel** because it can cause serious confusion to other programmers and does not follow conventions, I think I understood what you are after:

```
class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    // protected $table = 'abstract';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'created_at',
        'created_by' ,
        'abstract_no',
        'pr_number',
        'proc_details',
        'office',
        'requestor_name'
    ];

    public function offices()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Office', 'id', 'office');
    }

    public function purchaseRequestItemModels()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PurchaseRequestItemModel', 'id', 'pr_number');
    }

}

Class Office extends Model
{

    ...

    public function abstractModels()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AbstractModel', 'office', 'id');
    }

}

class PurchaseRequestItemModel extends Model
{
    ...

    public function abstractModels()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AbstractModel', 'pr_number', 'id');
    }

}
```

You can then proceed to just instanciate AbstractModel and catch linked offices and PRNumbers as bellow:

```
$abstract = AbstractModel::find($id);

//These method calls return Objects of the type:
// Office
$abstract->offices();

//PurchaseRequestItemModel
$abstract->purchaseRequestItemModels();
```

Now, please check [coding standards](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) to further improve your semantics and code quality as it will help A LOT  in the future!

**NOTE:** I understand you might have other `classes` that talk with each other and you can achieve the same result if you create a relationship as I exemplified above.

Further relationship explanation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: thank you for your answer, the reason why I don't use the eloquent models that much when it comes to database relationships is that, I didn't understand that much how it works in eloquent. Hopefully I can improve my code quality, I'm still learning the proper ways

Comment: You are welcome! Programing is a constant learn. You are going down a path we all share ^^ best of luck on your progress!